# data loaded success event for angular 7

Tags: angular6, angular7, angular8

How to show success message after loaded table data in angular 7 same like ajax success event method.ANyone know the answer please help to find the solution.

app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this._dataService.getTabeData(url).subscribe(res=> {

            this.myData = res.tableData;

 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check statusCode `res.statusCode === 200` so it is okay.(or any other success statusCode of your API)

```
 this._dataService.getTabeData(url).subscribe(res=> {

            this.myData = res.tableData;
           if(res.statusCode === 200) {
             console.log("SUCCESS")
            }
 });
```

Comment: Getting array values only like  tableData:{ id:"1",name:"Robert"},{ id:"2",name:"Michel"},....ect

Comment: Can you show your method  this._dataService.getTabeData

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `res`

if your `res` is like this `{status: "success", data: [{ id:"1",name:"Robert"}..]}`

You can show success event by

```
if(res['status'] == 'success')
    { 
     //do something
    }
```